# Is Chappie meant to be a prequel to Elysium?

Tags: elysium, district-9, chappie

When I watched Elysium, I could not help thinking that the droids:

[image: Elysium droid]

bore more than a passing resemblance to Chappie:

[image: Chappie]

I'm wondering if that is a coincidence or, since they have the [same director](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neill_Blomkamp), if it is intended in-universe? Do Chappie and Elysium (and possibly District 9<sup>1</sup>) occur in the same universe? Are they meant to be related?

<sub>1 Like Chappie, Elysium and District 9 both feature strong South African characters and occur in a similar dystopian future.</sub>

Comment: I don't think so. Other than the similar design of the robots, there is nothing to suggest that they would be linked - for example, the aliens in District 9 are never mentioned in either of the other two, and a significant technological advancement made in Chappie isn't present in District 9 either.

Comment: Also, I don't want to have to research this. Going through old interviews with Blomkamp and seeing how hopeful everyone was that we had a new sci-fi auteur on our hands is just depressing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, no, *Chappie* and *Elysium* (and *District 9*) are not set in the same universe, confirmed by [this interview](http://news.moviefone.com/2015/03/04/neill-blomkamp-chappie-exclusive/), in which when asked "But there's not a shared universe?", he replied "Definitely not".

It is worth pointing out that in 2004, Blomkamp released a [short film called *Tetra Vaal*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTnxP7e7-YA) which contains a very similar looking robot design. It is likely that he simply liked the design of that robot so much that he went on to use it in both *Elysium* and *Chappie*.

Admittedly the robot design is slightly different in *Elysium*, but this is most likely due to the fact that Syd Mead (who helped design parts of *Aliens* and *Blade Runner*) was involved with the design process of *Elysium*.

Comment: There are still (with the "Distict 9") according to director part of [thematic trilogy](http://au.ign.com/articles/2015/03/05/district-9-director-neill-blomkamp-has-an-idea-for-district-10)